# display a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a problem with my stored procedure, when I run I have this error:

> *ADO EROR: Incorrect syntax near the keyword " where "*

I want to display 2 fileds counted by on filed where i have companies that area selected by year 2012

This is my query:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE ProceduraCalculareAuto
      AS
       SELECT ФИРМА.НаимПредпр
         FROM  dbo.ФИРМА  LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.АВТОМОБ ON dbo.АВТОМОБ.КодПредпр = dbo.ФИРМА.КодПредпр INNER JOIN
                      dbo.КАРНЕТ ON dbo.КАРНЕТ.КодПредпр = dbo.ФИРМА.КодПредпр 
                  INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Tegaci = COUNT
            (CASE [КодПриц/Тягач]
                  WHEN 4 THEN  [КодПриц/Тягач] 
                END),
            Auto = COUNT
         (CASE [КодПриц/Тягач]
          WHEN 3 THEN  [КодПриц/Тягач] 
                         END)
          FROM     dbo.АВТОМОБ
                 GROUP BY dbo.АВТОМОБ.[КодПриц/Тягач] )
      WHERE(dbo.КАРНЕТ.ДтВыдачи BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-01-01 00:00:00',  
       102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-12-31 00:00:00', 102))
      GROUP BY ФИРМА.НаимПредпр

 RETURN
```

Comment: is that really a valid column names? O.o

Comment: please provide the schema

Comment: yes thay are witten in other language

Comment: Cyrillic, used in Russia and some other countries.

Comment: Yarolsav this is russian and the words too :), cyrillic is only used only in countries that speak a language but the words they are write in Cyrillic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing an alias for the subquery.  In SQL Server every derived table and subquery needs an alias. You are also missing the `ON` clause to join the subquery to the rest of your query:

```
SELECT ФИРМА.НаимПредпр
FROM  dbo.ФИРМА  
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.АВТОМОБ 
  ON dbo.АВТОМОБ.КодПредпр = dbo.ФИРМА.КодПредпр 
INNER JOIN dbo.КАРНЕТ 
  ON dbo.КАРНЕТ.КодПредпр = dbo.ФИРМА.КодПредпр 
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT Tegaci = COUNT
            (CASE [КодПриц/Тягач]
                  WHEN 4 THEN  [КодПриц/Тягач] 
                END),
            Auto = COUNT
         (CASE [КодПриц/Тягач]
          WHEN 3 THEN  [КодПриц/Тягач] 
                         END)
  FROM     dbo.АВТОМОБ
  GROUP BY dbo.АВТОМОБ.[КодПриц/Тягач] 
)  src 
   -- this needs an alias and it also needs a join condition. 
  on etc = src.
WHERE(dbo.КАРНЕТ.ДтВыдачи BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-01-01 00:00:00',  
       102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-12-31 00:00:00', 102))
GROUP BY ФИРМА.НаимПредпр
```

I am guessing on the join columns, but I think you might want this:

```
SELECT ФИРМА.НаимПредпр
FROM  dbo.ФИРМА  
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.АВТОМОБ 
  ON dbo.АВТОМОБ.КодПредпр = dbo.ФИРМА.КодПредпр 
INNER JOIN dbo.КАРНЕТ 
  ON dbo.КАРНЕТ.КодПредпр = dbo.ФИРМА.КодПредпр 
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT Tegaci = COUNT
            (CASE [КодПриц/Тягач]
                  WHEN 4 THEN  [КодПриц/Тягач] 
                END),
            Auto = COUNT
         (CASE [КодПриц/Тягач]
          WHEN 3 THEN  [КодПриц/Тягач] 
                         END),
      dbo.АВТОМОБ.[КодПриц/Тягач]
  FROM     dbo.АВТОМОБ
  GROUP BY dbo.АВТОМОБ.[КодПриц/Тягач] 
)  src 
   -- this needs an alias and it also needs a join condition. 
  on dbo.АВТОМОБ.[КодПриц/Тягач] = src.[КодПриц/Тягач] 
WHERE(dbo.КАРНЕТ.ДтВыдачи BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-01-01 00:00:00',  
       102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-12-31 00:00:00', 102))
GROUP BY ФИРМА.НаимПредпр
```

Comment: @Sergio between the closing parentheses on your subquery and the `WHERE` clause you have to place a name for the subquery.  I used `src` in my example.  You also need to add a join condition for the subquery.